# Global user object in Portable Class Library (MVVM)

Tags: c#, mvvm, portable-class-library

This is my first attempt at creating a PCL and using MVVM so I'm sort of confused on how to proceed from here.

I'm trying to create a venue booking system where we can post comments and such. But every time I create a booking/comment, I send to send some user verification data to the server. How would I persist this user data across multiple pages/viewmodels? Or is it better for me to just retrieve that data from storage whenever I need it?